# I cannot create the table in latex, why?

Tags: tables

I am trying to create a table in LaTeX. I have a file with few tables, and when I try to create one more, it yields the following errors:

There are several problems at this line:

- Missing number, treated as zero.`\begin{table}[hbt]` (followed by: )
- Undefined control sequence:  `\begin{table}[hbt]` (followed by: )
- Too many unprocessed floats. `\begin{table}[hbt]` (followed by: )

If I create this table without the `table` environment, it works. But when I surround it with `\begin{table}[hbt] ... \end{table}`, I get the mentioned errors. I have no idea what is wrong, because all previous table are identical (copy/paste).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 5):

One of your tables is big and cannot be placed either at the top or at the bottom (tables cannot exceed 70% of the page height, in order to be placed at the top or bottom of a page).

Since you don't specify `p` (page) placement, all tables remain in the queue until it overflows its capacity. Leave out the optional `[htb]` argument or add also a `p`.